# CSS multiple columns layout: incorrect column splitting

Tags: html, css

There seems to be a bug in calculation of multi column css property, present in all browsers I have checked in (latest Chrome, IE11 and Firefox). If you have 9 items in your list, and try to split it in 4 columns, the last column is always empty.

Are there any workarounds, something that will split it 3/2/2/2? Thanks in advance.

```css
ul {
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  background-color: gray;
}
li {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The column number exactly is 4 but minimum item per column is 3 items so if you add one more `li`, it will show in the last column

Comment: 9 % 4 != 0. Basically, why should that work? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: its not about calculation its about the column height when one column have 3 items others also create space for an other

Comment: yes, this problem is not about the `ul` height even set its height may effect to the number of column, but it's not solve the real problem

Answer (score 1):

http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

It looks like the column-* has alot of issues with different browsers.  In your example if you were to add 1 more li element, then you can see it will fill itself in on the 4th column.  My guess is its a divisibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is working in same way that it supposed to work, there is enough space in 3 columns for 9 items that's why its not going into 4th, reduce height and it will be divide in more columns. or add more `li` that will go in 4th column

```css
ul {
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  background-color: gray;
  height:50px;
}
li {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem is that i need a dynamic height, for example if more elements will be added down the line.

Comment: Then there shouldn't be any problem. Column will work fine.

Comment: @downvoter! Please explain your downvote, so I can improve answer.

Comment: if i will set the height to a fixed number, and add more list items afterwards, they will overflow the ul and will not be visible

Comment: Use auto fill for columns, that will be filled according to element height.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
.keeptogether{
display:inline-block;
width:100%
}
```

```css
ul {
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  background-color: gray;
}
li {
  background-color: tomato;
}
.keeptogether {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<ul>
<div class="keeptogether">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</div>
<div class="keeptogether">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</div>
<div class="keeptogether">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</div>
<div class="keeptogether">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: You cannot put a div between ul and li elements, that is invalid html.